# Putting barcode scan result into Excel table

Tags: excel, powerapps

I'm still new to PowerApps. Initially what I wanted was an app that will scan a QR or barcode, display the result and email it to me. I got that working without much problem.

```
Set(varSingleScan,BarcodeScanner1.Value); Notify(Label1.Text);
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(User().Email,"Scan",User().FullName & " " &   _
  varSingleScan,{Importance:"Normal"});
```

Now I want to put the result, the user name, and a timestamp into an Excel spreadsheet. I made an Excel file in OneDrive, created a table with columns in one of the spreadsheets, and linked it to the app. I'm not sure what to do next. I tried adding code to the OnScan event like:

`QRCodes.Contributer = User().FullName;`

But that doesn't work. I tried looking online, but all the videos start with creating the Excel table first then creating the app - not the other way around. Is there a way to do this or do I have to start over and somehow change the input for a new row to use the Barcode scanner tool?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give PowerApps an instruction to write a record somewhere.

Update(), UpdateIf(), Patch().. in this case, read up on the patch statement ;-)